# Laravel migration reset/refresh error ORA-01758 on Oracle Database

Tags: php, database, oracle, laravel, migration

My Laravel migration keeps getting error when **reset/refresh**:

```
ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL)
```

The migration is as follow:

```php
public function up()
{
   Schema::table('kasbank', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('name_bn');
        $table->dropColumn('id_rekon');
        $table->string('name_kb')->after('kode');
        $table->integer('id_rek')->nullable();
   });
}
    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('kasbank', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('id_rek');
        $table->dropColumn('name_kb');
        $table->integer('id_rekon')->nullable();
        $table->string('name_bn')->after('kode');
   });
}
```

FYI, column `id_rekon` is initially nullable in the database.

What's missed from my migration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your table is not empty and the current rows will be given NULL as a default value, but the column is not allowed to be NULL.

You should be able to get around it by setting a default value.

From the Oracle docs:

> However, a column with a NOT NULL constraint can be added to an
>   existing table if you give a default value; otherwise, an exception is
>   thrown when the ALTER TABLE statement is executed.

Try:

```
$table->integer('id_rek')->default($value)->nullable();
```

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's likely working though. But eventually I've recreated a local development database from scratch, so I didn't find the same error again, then.